# Comparing significance of categorical levels in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, inference, multiple-comparisons, odds-ratio

I'm running a logistic regression on some data that has a binary outcome and several input variables, one of which is categorical with 5 levels. I'm using one of these levels as the reference, and so interpreting the ORs for the other 4 levels is straightforward - these are "relative" to level 0.

But what I'm not sure about is whether we can say anything about differences between the ORs of the other levels without completely re-running the analysis. Say I want to compare level 1 and level 2 - if $OR_1 = 1.75$ with a 95% CI $1.56-1.93$ and $OR_2 = 2.35$ with a CI $2.08-2.65$, can we say that the OR for level 2 is "significantly higher" than the OR for level 1? Or what if the difference is even more dramatic, something like $OR_2 = 9.01$ $(8.5-9.5)$. Obviously these are all in relation to an OR of 1.00 for the reference group, but can we make any comparisons between other levels? For additional context, all of the levels have ORs with significant p<0.05.

I would like to avoid re-running the analysis if possible, as using level 0 as the reference group is what makes sense for this use case, and I'd prefer not to have to worry about multiple comparisons.

Comment: Because the problem is no different than in other forms of regression, [searching our site for "contrast"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+contrast+test+significant+is%3Aanswer+score%3A2) will be fruitful.

Comment: Some relevant posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285210/what-to-do-in-a-multinomial-logistic-regression-when-all-levels-of-dv-are-of-int/544656#544656, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436618/how-to-test-between-level-significance-in-logistic-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481839/hypothesis-testing-for-logistic-regression-with-categorical-predictor